# Tortoise SVN Merge Multiple Branches into Trunk

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn

I know merging with Tortoise SNV has been discussed (at length) but I cannot find an answer to my situation. I understand I can merge a dev branch into the trunk using the merge wizard, but what is the proper workflow if I want to merge ***multiple*** branches into the trunk?

In my situation, I created three dev branches (one for each developer) from a project trunk. Initially, the dev branches and the trunk were identical. The developers are also working in separate areas of the project, so multiple people are not working with the same files. So, for example, I have trunk, b1, b2, and b3 where **trunk = b1 = b2 = b3**.

Now, after some development, I want to merge the changes from each dev branch back into the trunk. This is where I am getting confused. I have read that you can simply merge each branch into the trunk, one at a time (committing the changes from each branch before merging the next one) since they all share the same ancestory and Tortoise is smart enough to know what should be changed. So:

```
b1 -> merge to trunk -> commit trunk (now trunk has b1 changes)
b2 -> merge to trunk -> commit trunk (now trunk has b1 and b2 changes)
b3 -> merge to trunk -> commit trunk (now trunk has b1, b2, and b3 changes)
```

I have also read that you should merge the dev branch changes into the other dev branches, then merge into the trunk so that there are not overwrite issues (which I thought tortoise was smart enough to avoid). So:

```
b3 -> merge to b2 -> commit b2 (now b2 has b3 changes)
b2 -> merge to b1 -> commit b1 (now b1 and b2 and b3 changes)
b1 -> merge to trunk -> commit trunk (now trunk has b1, b2, and b3 changes)
```

Please advise if one method is better than the other or if one is flawed. My concern is if I merge changes from one branch, then merge changes from another branch, I will be undoing changes from the first merge operation or causing issues with the metadata.

I am using **TortoiseSVN Version 1.8.8, build 25755** and **Subversion 1.8.10**.

**Thanks!**

Comment: Regardless of which workflow you follow you shouldn't worry about undoing changes. Subversion will flag merge conflicts and you can review changes before committed them. You can always revert any operation on a working copying, including a merge operation. It's only recorded when you commit the changes. That said, you can definitely save yourself from merging difficulties by using a proper workflow. See my answer for more info on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should merge the trunk into your branch before merging your branch back to the trunk. Prior to Subversion 1.8 you had to specify the `--reintegrate` flag when merging to the trunk, but Subversion takes care of that through the new [automatic reintegration merge](https://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#auto-reintegrate) capabilities. The following workflow is described in the [basic merging section](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html) of the SVN book:

1. merge trunk to b1
2. commit changes on b1
3. merge b1 to trunk
4. commit changes on trunk
5. delete b1

Repeat for b2 and b3.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Can you tell me why you want to merge the trunk into the dev branch before merging the dev branch into the trunk? I have read about doing this before, but do not understand why one would want to do this knowing that the trunk has not changed. Is it just a good practice?

Comment: If the trunk hasn't changes you don't need to merge the trunk into your branch. In the general case there is the possibility of conflicts and it's best practice to resolve those conflicts on the branch before merging to the trunk. Once you've merged the HEAD of the trunk into your branch, resolved all conflicts  and committed the changes, you'll have no conflicts when doing a reintegration merge of your branch into the trunk (reintegration merge is implicit when running a merge in 1.8). Note that the trunk will have changed after you reintegrate b1, that's why I described a general workflow.

Comment: I will read it again. Maybe it will make more sense the second time around. Also, I think I just answered my own question. The merges from the trunk into the dev branches prior to the branch to trunk merge is so the current dev branch getting merged gets the changes from the previous merges. Essentially doing the second workflow I showed, but through the trunk itself and correcting conflicts. Correct? Thanks again for the clarification.

Comment: Yes, without going into details as to why it's better to only merge to and from the trunk in your case, that's correct.